# asp.net mvc 4 styling labels and texts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Working on an asp.net MVC-4 project and would want to style form elements using bootstrap.
What is the VB.Net equivalent for applying the Bootstrap styles to form label, input and validation message?
Have tried tweaking the c# equivalent but can't quite seem to get it right *(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { @class = "form-control"})*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> New With { .class= 
>       "form-control" }

Instead of this

> new { @class = "form-control" }

Comment: You're welcome. BTW: in StackExchange community when you obtain a proper answer you can click a green tick to mark it as correct.